How many bits would be required to store 2D FDCT result of 8-bit sample data?
The 2D FDCT can be expressed as a multiplication between an 8x8 matrix of 8-bit integers (lets call it A) and another 8x8 matrix containing fraction values (lets call it B) that are all less than 1. Matrix multiplication involves multiply accumulate operation.
Since we are adding an 8-bit value 8 times, we need 3 more bits to store the result. Thus, the first pass of FDCT needs 11 bits. When we take this data and multiply it with B again, we again need 3 more bits to store the result. Thus, the final result needs 14 bits. The result from each stage of FDCT is a signed value.
Now when I look at the JPEG standard (ITU T.81), it implies that the 2D FDCT result that goes through quantization is 12 bits and not 14 bits. How is this possible?
